# Counter Example of Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

I came across this question:

**Question**: Let $f$ be a real continuous function defined on [0,1] such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.  Prove or give a counter-example to the following:

a) If $f'$ exists a.e. in $[0,1]$, then $\int_0^1 f' dx  = 1$.

b) If $f'$ is absolutely continuous in $[0,1]$, then $\int_0^1 f' dx = 1$.

c) If $f'$ is non-decreasing in $[0,1]$, then $\int_0^1 f' dx = 1$.

**Thoughts**: I feel like I can just take $f'(x) = x^{1/2}$ for all three parts and thus I get a counter example for all three conditions?  Am I missing something or is this correct?

Comment: I have already realized that my example doesn't work since it violates that $f(1) \ne 1$.

Comment: Note first of all that these are all very similar to the fundamental theorem of calculus, so you're certainly not going to find a counterexample by looking at nice smooth functions anything like $x^{1/2}$.

Comment: (b) is true I think, apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and continuity alone is enough. What integral is this btw?

Comment: Just your typical $f(x)$ function in general.

Comment: Dear @user0430 I see that, although you have already asked 18 question in this site and received answers in most of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that is constant on each middle third in the construction of the Cantor set. To make it continuous and yet pass through $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, you need to 'slowly' go up. The way to do this is to iteratively build the function by defining it on the middle thirds first, such that the function on each third has value halfway between the value on the adjacent thirds in earlier steps of the Cantor construction. The remaining function values can be obtained by limits.

It then remains to prove that the function solves (a) and (c). On the other hand, (b) is true but involves a fair bit of machinery. How much do you know?

Comment: Is this Cantor's function? If it is then I'm not sure if $f'$ exists on $[0, 1]$ for (c).